# Dynamic Transcoding and streaming

Tags: php, video, mobile, streaming, media

im trying to work out the best way to have my site dynamicly transcode and stream video files to users who are mostly on mobile devices, site is php/mysql based and running on a windows 2003 server which i have full access to, any ideas how best to do this - id rather not need to transcode videos on upload if possible

Comment: I don't know the answer - but I *do* know it's best not done in PHP. Also, you will need to specify some formats and what exactly you need by "transcode". From where to where?

Comment: This is a very heavy process, so I would do it on upload just once.

Comment: Maybe [Alembik](http://alembik.sourceforge.net/) helps you.

Comment: +1 on jifox's comment- it's a very bad idea to transcode for each request if you're planning to have more than a few users - it simply won't scale.

Answer (score 1):

For your services consider something with some oomph: [Inlet](http://www.inlethd.com), [Digital Rapids](http://www.digital-rapids.com/Products/IndividualProducts.aspx), or [Rhozet](http://www.rhozet.com/). Some of these players offer some form of live-stream encoding but you'll generally have limitations on hardware. They all have suitable APIs for interacting with the hardware and profiles.

You can also consider using public transcoding services but keep the assets private. It's not quite as elegant as a roll-your-own but it does solve the problem.

Transcode-/Encode-on-upload will probably serve your needs better if the volume of content or traffic increases. Real-time transcoding has many hurdles including race situations and bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar similar situation in my past at that time I had book marked this like below which has some very interesting stuff ,

[php video transcoder](http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=1941)

I am sorry If this didn't help you